# faster search of file in s3 bucket in aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, autoscroll

I am searching for a specific file in a S3 bucket that has a lot of files. In my application I get an error of 403 access denied, and with s3cmd I am getting an error of 403 (Forbidden) if I try to get a file from the bucket. My problem is that I am not sure if the permissions are the problem (because I can get other files) or the file isn't present on the bucket. I have started to search in the Amazon console interface, but I am scrolling for hours and I have not arrived at "4...." (I am still at "39...") and the file I am looking for is in a folder "C03215".

So, is there a faster way to verify that the file exists on the bucket? Or is there a way to do auto-scrolling and meanwhile doing something else (because if I do not scroll nothing new is loading)?

P.S.: I have no permission to list with s3cmd

Comment: Have you used AWS CLI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding accelerating the scrolling in the console

Like you I have many thousands of objects that takes an eternity to scroll through to in the console.

I recently discovered though how to jump straight to a specific path/folder in the console that is going to save my mouse finger and my sanity!

This will only work for folders though not the actual leaf objects themselves.

In the URL bar of your browser when viewing a bucket you will see something like:

```
console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=eu-west-1#&bucket=your-bucket-name&prefix=
```

If you append your object's path after the prefix and hit enter you assume that it should jump to that object but it does nothing (in chrome at least).

However if you append your object's path after the prefix, hit enter and then hit refresh (f5) the console will reload at your specified location.

e.g.

```
console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=eu-west-1#&bucket=your-bucket-name&prefix=development/2015-04/TestEvent/93edfcbg-5e27-42d3-a2f9-3d86a63d27f9/
```

There was much joy in our office when this was figured out!

Comment: Yes! That is it! If you know your folder, or path, you can to that path by adding in the `...prefix=your/path` relative to the bucket. It works

Answer (score 1):

The only "faster way" is to have the `s3:ListBucket` permission on the bucket, because, as you have noticed, S3's response to a `GET` request is intentionally ambiguous if you don't.

> If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the `s3:ListBucket` permission.
>
> If you have the `s3:ListBucket` permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
>
> If you don’t have the `s3:ListBucket` permission, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Also, there's not a way to accelerate scrolling in the console.